# Pushing back button/escape reverts text in Input Field

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using an Input Field in a Unity 3D game. When I enter text on my Windows 10 Mobile, and push the back button to dismiss the keyboard, Unity thinks I want to clear the Input Field. This behavior is not even mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html) and I have not found a way to override it. I'd like to make it so the user can use the back button to dismiss the keyboard without reverting the Input Field. Any suggestions? Is this just a bug with Unity?

Comment: You can detect if the touch is outside inputField and than dismiss the keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the source code of InputField here: https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/0155c39e05ca5d7dcc97d9974256ef83bc122586/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/InputField.cs?at=5.2&fileviewer=file-view-default

Apparently, clearing the field on escape is made by design. look at line 980 - 984:

```
case KeyCode.Escape:
{
     m_WasCanceled = true;
     return EditState.Finish;
}
```

What you can try is to create your own subclass of InputField and override the function

```
protected EditState KeyPressed(Event evt)
```

Of course it is not really clean, since you'll have to copy everything that the base InputField does in this function, except for lines 980 - 984.

Answer (score 1):

The function KeyPressed cant be overridden.

I just added that in my function that listens on the value changes of the inputField:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape)) {
    return;
}
```

And it does exactly what is necessary :)